# The constructor of hyperboloid in pbrt-v3

Tags: rendering, computational-geometry, geometry

The [book](http://pbrt.org/) omitted the explanation of [the constructor of hyperboloid](https://github.com/mmp/pbrt-v3/blob/master/src/shapes/hyperboloid.cpp#L43).

Could someone give some explanations about:

1. Why the arguments are two points?
2. What are the meanings of ***ah*** and ***ch***?
3. Why is there a while loop?

Answer (score 1):

1. They must define it as a surface of revolution of a line segment.
2. From the comments, they are probably the *a* and *c* coefficients of the canonical hyperboloid equation. With a surface of revolution, *a* == *b* so no need to store *b* separately.
3. It's clearly related to figuring out *ah* and *ch* from the line segment. I can't say more precisely without working out the math involved. I'll leave that to someone with more free time.

Comment: A surface of revolution of a line segment would be a disk, cylinder, or cone, no? I can't see how you would get a hyperboloid; it should be a surface of revolution of a hyperbola. I'm guessing the hyperbola is fit to pass through the two points, or something like that.

Comment: @NathanReed It's not intuitive at all but it is possible. Look at the diagrams on the right side of the [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid#Parametric_representations).